# Android Google +1 Button Issues

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have implemented the Google+ one button as outlined here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend.

However clicking the +1 button does not increment the counter and sharing shares an empty post. I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried various solutions.

Here's my code for implementing the button:

```
private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

//In onCreate():
mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
        mPlusOneButton.initialize(url, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Here's my XML for the button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        plus:size="standard"
        plus:annotation="inline" />
```

Comment: Also have the same issue. Found in logs: Error E/PlusOneActivity﹕ Intent missing required arguments. But don't have any ideas how to fix it. Checked intent that sent from app, so all information included except account.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with the latest Play Services unfortunately - https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1127&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

Reason of this issue was

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in Manifest for current activity.

Could you please share your code maybe I can help.

In my case I change code to

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Regards